# JAX-WS Netbeans how to enable compression web service client

Tags: web-services, netbeans, compression, jax-ws

I used the Web Service Client wizard in Netbeans 7.1.2, however when I try to call one the methods i receive the following error:

***javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Exception: Compression is Not Enabled,This Web Service expects clients to support GZIP,Deflate Compression***

The generated skeleton files are numerous and I am unable to work out how to enable compression. Can anyone please advise?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are four things to consider here. There's a **request** and a **response** and there's a **client** and **server**. When talking about compression it is important to be precise as to which of these cases we are targeting. I read the poster's question as being about the client side of things as it seems the server is already doing compression. (in fact it seems it mandates the client to be able to handle compression).

Here's a little background: Compression hints is a standard part of the HTTP protocol. The client will indicate to the server that it is willing to accept a compressed response by sending appropriate HTTP headers with the request. Equally the server will indicate if it has sent a compressed response by an appropriate HTTP header element in the response. The client can also send a compressed request.

These are the relevant HTTP headers elements:

- `Content-encoding` : If this is set it means "I'm sending you an encoded (e.g. compressed) message". Both the client can use this (on the request) and well as the server (on the response).
- `Accept-encoding` : If this is set it means "I can understand these types of encodings (e.g. compression methods), so feel free to send me data which is encoded in that format".

The typical value of these two header elements are "gzip" which is by far the most common compression method used by HTTP servers and HTTP clients. There's also "deflate" but stick with "gzip".

Let's start from the beginning: The **request** from the client to the server.:

It is actually quite rare to see this compressed. The reason is that the client cannot know in advance if the server can understand a compressed request. So it is generally best not to attempt this. Typically this is not a problem as it is most often the response that is big. If it is absolutely necessary to compress the request then you would need to first somehow query the server for its capabilities or be absolutely sure that it can handle a compressed request.

Then to the more interesting part: the **response** from the server to the client.

First of all the client needs to tell the server that he's willing to accept a compressed response. This is done on the request (duh!). The general method of how to add a HTTP header element to a JAX-WS outbound request is explained in the Metro guide [here](http://metro.java.net/2.1.1/guide/HTTP_headers.html). So you would do like this:

```
SomeWebService someWS = service.getMyWebServicePort();
((BindingProvider)someWS).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
    Collections.singletonMap("Accept-Encoding",Collections.singletonList("gzip")));
```

You might say: "Won't this replace *all* of the HTTP header elements and replace it with a single element header?". Technically true but at this point JAX-WS hasn't yet added any HTTP header. JAX-WS will add its own header elements later. If you monitor the HTTP header that the server receives you'll now see something like this:

```
content-type : text/xml;charset="utf-8"
accept-encoding : gzip
soapaction : "http://blahblah"
accept : text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
user-agent : JAX-WS RI 2.1.5-hudson-$BUILD_NUMBER-
host : localhost:8084
connection : keep-alive
content-length : 216
```

The "accept-encoding" element wouldn't have been there without our explicit action. (good question why JAX-WS doesn't add this by default ??)

Now you're done with the client side. The previous poster has explained how to add compression ability on the server-side. What is relevant to note is that compression on the server-side (as long as we talk about compressing the *response*) is handled solely by the container, e.g. by Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc, and not by your code. You just need to flip a switch in the container's configuration.

Almost done. The server is now free to send your client a gzip compressed response but at the sole discretion of the server. The server may do it or not. You don't know this.

Your final question should be:  "How do I in my JAX-WS client handle a compressed response?" or more broadly "how would my JAX-WS client cope with compressed vs uncompressed responses?". The good news is that this is handled transparently by JAX-WS. There's nothing you need to do. JAX-WS will automatically detect that it receives a compressed response from the server (it simply looks at the HTTP headers in the response) and it will automatically decompress it for you.  Voila!

So, dear poster, I would say that most likely, if you are using a recent version of JAX-WS, your client will already now how to handle a compressed response. However since the client hasn't explicitly told the server that it can understand a compressed response the server assumes this not to be the case and hence gives you that error. That is my guess to what you are seeing.

Ohh, and one more thing. HTTP Header element names (they are rightfully called "header fields") are case-insensitive as per RFC 2616. So you see this spelled in lots of different ways in different postings.

Comment: For me JAX-WS didn't automatically decompress my response, I've needed to add 
``client = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceProxy);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());``

Answer (score -1):

You can enable compression better from the application server configuration. From your question, you're most likely using glassfish or tomcat(I'm more of a tomcat person). For glassfish, you can enable compression by adding the following to your `domain.xml`

```
         <property name="compression" value="on"/>
```

Or if you're managing your server via the admin console, use [this visual guide](http://www.vikasing.com/2010/01/enable-gzip-compression-on-glassfish-v3.html). For tomcat add

```
         compression="on"
```

to your tomcat `<Connector/>` element in the `server.xml` config file.

To actually send a compressed JAX-WS request, simply indicate your intention to send a compressed request by adding the compression header to your HTTP payload

```
    Map<String, List<String> theHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
theHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));//this indicates you're sending a compressed request
theHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip")); //this says you're willing to accept a compressed response
Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((bindingProvider) proxy)
        .getRequestContext(); //get access to the request context of your webservice request
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
```

The above logic is better performed from a webservice [handler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13734/handlers.htm) as a matter of design

Comment: From the question it seems he has an existing web service towards which he has created a ws client. The client gets back a compressed reply and chokes. Then you tell him how to enable compression on the server side but clearly that is already the case. What he needs is for JAX-WS to understand the compressed reply it gets back from the server.

Comment: @nolan6000, What part of my answer indicates that it's a webservice side-only solution? how exactly does the client [indicate to the webservice that it supports compression](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+enable+a+webservice+client+to+support+compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) hmm? If you disagree, please enlighten us by suggesting a solution.

Comment: The first half of the answer deals with how to enable compression on the server-side .. which I deduct from the original posting is already the case. Then your answer says "To actually send a compressed JAX-WS request ..": again here it deals with the wrong side of the fence. It would be the response that is interesting for the poster. Granted that how to do this is actually part of your code example ("Accept-Encoding") but it is mentioned nowhere in the text. I did not have a solution at the time when I made my comment. That does not mean that I cannot comment that the solution is off target.

Comment: Have added solution. Somewhat chatty. Sorry about that.

Comment: @nolan6000, the first part of my answer is necessary because the application server on which the client is running needs to be able to decompress compressed responses and also possibly compress requests. All the code sample does is to advertise that the client is compression ready. Should a compressed response return, the application server would not be in a position to decompress it without proper configuration

Comment: Not to be an a.. but again there's a necessity to keep the wording accurate. You wrote "the application server on which the client is running needs to be able to decompress compressed responses and also possibly compress requests". Hmm. The server is the RECEIVER of requests and the SENDER of responses so the sentence is nonsense to me. Or what?

Comment: Disregard previous comment. I think I got what you mean now. You are assuming that the poster's web service consumer is executing inside an application server? It is the server-side of a web service that MUST run inside a servlet engine (to use a more accurate word than "application server"). Of course the web service consumer MAY also run from inside a container but there's nothing in the poster's text to suggest that. Indeed when you create a Web Service Client in Netbeans it will normally just be a standard Java SE app.